# Show items from a DB in a Post

Tags: posts

How can i add a cicle in a post to show all the images from a DB , i was wonderinf if is possible implement a for or some stuff like that , to bring all the items and show them or print them in a post

Comment: With all images, do you mean all the image attachments that you've ever uploaded to the Media Library or do you have some kind of custom database table for the images? Should the images display in every post or in some particular post?

Comment: i have 1500 images in a DB , and i already have a .php file that makes that , but with local host , now i wanna implement this in posts , the posts have a default thumbnail image , this appears in every single one posts that i add , but i wanna make 1500 posts but with the image from the db , i mean each post with its respective image from DB

Comment: Not to the media library , if is possible from a DB , so , i would like to have 1500 posts and each one with differente image ( of course cause are 1500 different images ) , but i can't find the .php file where are the functions or where to modify this in the wordpress files